# What is the best schema design when user can post a free structure data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I was thinking about a form creator application. user can design their own form, they can add fields as they want.

for example, one user may submit a hire form, in this form maybe include some fields like 'work experices','level of education',etc. he provide some selection options of these fields, then when he publish out this form, and the jobhunter submit it.  then he can view the results list, and maybe he need filter the people by 'work experices', so that means the field he just added in the form needs to me indexed.

in this case, how to design the schema in mongodb?

so far i can imaging is one `Forms` collection, with some normal fields like author,date,position,etc. and also a `content` field, all the user defined form data is stored in this field as a json object.

i will add index in this way in the example above

```
db.forms.createIndex({"content.workexp" : 1})
```

my question is:

1. if i do like this, what is the contra?
2. if i did index the custome field inside, what happened to other user's customize form data that with no such field?
3. is there a better solution to achieve the goal?

(updated)

i am going to design like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1jxj0m76yNl), as `forms` is record the form templates, and will mapping it to another collection (via `entity` field). in my example data, the first record in form as the `resume` form which is mapping to the `resumes` collection, what means new resume data which defined the structure fields in the first record of `forms`, will be stored in the `resumes` collection at last.

it looks good so far, however, because one form record mapping to one collection, that will make mass of collections. another problem is, if 2 records mapping to one same collection, that will make the structure can not keep the same.

this design is OK with small business own, however if my purporse is a platform to every body to create unlimit forms, that would be a problem.

Comment: Regarding schema design, I think there is no so-called best schema. One of the starting options might be like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I7Oclwg3KuE). You are operating a lot in the field level so they are stored as individual documents. This is easier to work with than storing them all into a single array

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this match with your requirements, but here is my opinion,

i assume that your users will be companies/organizations, and there will be some questions in the feature

- how if they need another form? `its needs form builders`
- I want to create form with field(s) to be `required` and/or `optional`

if we look at a big platforms, let say like [JIRA Software](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)

so, this is a bit copy from them :

there will be 3 schemas: `fields, forms, tables`

- `fields` collection
  this is should be public(anyone can see),

```js
let fields =
{
  _id: "ObjectId",
  name: "string", // my field
  fields: [
    {
      id: "ObjectId"
      type: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ["heading", "paragraph", "input", "checkbox"], // maybe you can add more types
      },
      name: { type: "string" }, //html standart
      text: { type: "string" }, //html standart
      label: { type: "string" }, //html standart
      placeholder: { type: ["string", "null"] }, //html standart
      required: { type: "boolean", enum: [true, false] }, //html standart
      fileID: { type: ["string", "null"] }, // may be needs type file(s)
    },
  ],
};
```

- `forms` collection

  In the FORM api, will need to create 2 collections, `forms`  and `fields`
  reason: let the users create any types fields(because any field will be a template)

  so we only need to check the fields length, `if(payload.fields.length > 0) create new fields`
  if fields length === 0, create new `fields`
  otherwise `fields = [ ObjectId(id)]`

```js
let forms =
{
  _id: "ObjectId",
  companyId: "ObjectId", //this is used to make this form will be own by the company
  name: "string", // work-experience,
  formRef: "reff", // optional, maybe you will need function like `copy` in the feature.
  fields: [
    {
      id: "ObjectId"
      type: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ["heading", "paragraph", "input", "checkbox"],
      },
      name: { type: "string" },
      text: { type: "string" },
      label: { type: "string" },
      placeholder: { type: ["string", "null"] },
      required: { type: "boolean", enum: [true, false] },
      fileID: { type: ["string", "null"] },
    },
  ],
};
```

- `tables` collection
  as a template form

```js
let tables = {
  _id: "ObjectId",
  companyId: "ObjectId",
  name: "string",
  formId: "ObjectId",
};
```

By using companyId in the table and form, we already reduce the map function.
let me know what your opinion